# Selecting similar elements in similar sub div's

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to select an array of elements using JQuery that are in separate sub div's.

i.e.

```
<div class="panelWrap">
                    <div id="dvStage1" class="milestoneWrap" runat="server">
                        <div class="grid_1 detailsWrap">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="detailsStage1"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid_1 dateWrap">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="completedDateStage1"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dvStage2" class="milestoneWrap" runat="server">
                        <div class="grid_1 detailsWrap">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="detailsStage2"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid_1 dateWrap">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="completedDateStage2"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dvStage3" class="milestoneWrap hidden" runat="server">
                        <div class="grid_1 detailsWrap">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="detailsStage3"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid_1 dateWrap">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="completedDateStage3"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

etc..

At run time, some of the stages are hidden depending on how many are needed.

I want to select the dateWrap div or the text box within it for each stage, but excluding those that have "hidden" in the class name.

e.g. selecting completedDateStage1 and completedDateStage2, but excluding completedDateStage3, as it's parent div is hidden.

I've toyed around with the :not and :contains selectors, but no luck so far.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with this : `$(".milestoneWrap:not(.hidden)").find(".dateWrap")`

(working exampe : http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/yFNpK/1/ )